# Is it normal to have air under a pool cover when it hasn't been used for a while?

Tags: pool

This will be the first year I have had a pool so I am really new at all this stuff.

I took a look under the winter cover of my pool and I noticed that my liner has gotten all wrinkled up like it moved or something. The water level is relatively low from the pool being closed. I was wondering if this is normal? Should it go back to normal when I put water back inside of it when I open the pool?

Comment: Did you empty the pool for the winter?

Comment: I had a pool company come and close it. They lowered the pool level somewhat and plugged the holes where the water enters the pool from the filter.

Comment: So it turned out to be nothing. Basically the PH of the water can effect the liner. By the time we opened the pool the wrinkle was completely gone. Note to self. Do not look under pool cover in March.